# Route does not match in test but is recognized in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am following [Michael Hartl's](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users) tutorial, chapter 10. Test `UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user` fails when trying to do `get edit_user_path(@user)`.

```
get edit_user_path(@user)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/users/762146111/edit", :controller=>"users"}
from /Users/cello/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:55:in `generate'
```

However:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path '/users/762146111/edit', method: :get
=> {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit", :id=>"762146111"}
```

Below is the code that might have a bug (**Rails 5.1.4**).

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'

  get  '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post 'signup', to: 'users#create'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'sessions/new'

  resources :users
end
```

**users_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @user       = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test 'should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user' do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:danger] = 'Please log in.'
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass an ID in routes?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Isn't this the way to perform user specific actions?

Comment: For controller specs, see the updated docs here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is defining an **Integration Test** (inherits from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`), whereas your above code is defining a **Controller Test** (inherits from `ActionController::TestCase`).

`get :edit, ...` is the correct syntax for a controller test, because it bypasses URL recognition and directly specifies the `:action`. This is confusing, and is one of several reasons that controller tests are now discouraged in favour of integration tests, which is probably what you want to create.

To do so, change:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
```

to:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

(Note the tutorial, somewhat confusingly, uses `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` as the base class both for tests it puts in `tests/integration/` *and* those it puts in `tests/controllers/`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use direct url with 'get' method in spec.

In your spec instead of

```
get edit_user_path(@user)
```

use

```
get :edit, params: { id: @user.id }
```

the same with

```
patch user_path(@user)
```

use `patch :update` instead

Comment: Thanks I'll check your suggestion. This is how it is provided in the tutorial though. Maybe it was supported in earlier versions.